# Removing extra space before an apostrophe in python

Tags: python

I was asked to write a program for a class that uses two lists. One list contains the names of 7 people (I used presidents' names), the other contains their 7 phone numbers. The goal of the program is for the user to enter the name of a friend and the program displays that friend's phone number. I have the program working just how I want it, but the output puts an extra space in it that I don't want.The output looks like this:

```
Your friend George Washington 's phone number is: 249-451-2869
```

I want to remove the space between "Washington" and "'s" so it reads more naturally. I tried different versions of strip() but could not get rid of the pesky space. Here is the main code for the program:

```
personName = nameGenerator() #function to allow user to enter name
nameIndex = IsNameInList(personName, Friends) #function that checks the user's input to see if input is #in the name list
print('Your friend',Friends[nameIndex],"\'s phone number is:",Phone_Numbers[nameIndex]) #Friends is name list, Phone_Numbers is numbers list, nameIndex stores the index of the proper name and phone number
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`print` adds spaces between arguments by default; pass `sep=''` (the empty string) to disable that. You'll need to add back spaces manually where you want them, but it's the minimal change:

```
print('Your friend ', Friends[nameIndex], "\'s phone number is: ", Phone_Numbers[nameIndex], sep='')
```

Alternatively, just use [an f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (or any other string formatting technique you prefer) to format it to a single string before printing:

```
print(f"Your friend {Friends[nameIndex]}'s phone number is: {Phone_Numbers[nameIndex]}")
```

Comment: The f-string format worked perfectly. I had never heard of it before but found a pretty good article on it when I googled it (https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). Thanks for the help.

Comment: @The_Redhawk: If you've ever [used `str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) before, it's pretty similar. None of [the formatting mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) is needed for your case, but when you need custom formatting, it's the same rules.

Answer (score 2):

When printing multiple, separate variables, Python automatically inserts spaces. You can use string concatenation instead to insert spaces only where you want.

```
personName = nameGenerator() #function to allow user to enter name
nameIndex = IsNameInList(personName, Friends) #function that checks the user's input to see if input is #in the name list
print('Your friend '+Friends[nameIndex]+"\'s phone number is: "+Phone_Numbers[nameIndex]) #Friends is name list, Phone_Numbers is numbers list, nameIndex stores the index of the proper name and phone number
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the way you concatenate the strings. Instead of

```
print(string1, string2, string3)
```

You can concatenate them like this:

```
print(string1, string2 + string3)
```

In your case:

```
print('Your friend',Friends[nameIndex] + "\'s phone number is:",Phone_Numbers[nameIndex])
```

A `+` sign will not generate a space automatically, unlike using a `,`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you change "parallel" to "two" in my post? The instructions from my book said parallel. Is there a difference?

Comment: I was just trying to get the refiner badge, there is no reason.